# xml to html to xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, xml, xslt

I have a big xml string that needs to be displayed as a web page. I can achieve this with xslt. Now the users will make changes to certain attributes of the xml displayed on the web page. 
When they are done I need to save it back in the same xml format with the modified values.

Please guide me on what would be the best method to handle this.

using asp.net + c#

Comment: Use XSLT for the transform back to XML. You'll need to display more information for more help on that though. What issue are you having?

Comment: As long as the HTML is valid XHTML, you can use XSLT to transform it back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried something like this in the past, and resorted to using two separate XSLT sheets, one to transform to (X)HTML, and another to transform the edited one back.

Unfortunately there isn't a 'generic' way of doing it, XSLT is a one way transform; e.g. if a stylesheet disregards an element altogether, there's obviously no way of writing an inverse XSLT that will restore it.

Another possibility is to have your XML->HTML stylesheet generate `id` attributes on input elements in the HTML, and give the value of that attribute a value that can easily be used as a lookup in your source XML. Then you can probably just iterate through each such element in the HTML, and lookup the related element in the source and replace the value. Or the other way round, go through each element in your source, and find the value in the HTML, either works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this utility:

http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csHtmlToXmlRef.html

It might be possible to use XSLT to transform it back to HTML too, but without seeing the markup it's tough to tell.